# Crystal Report, Sum a field only if a value is null

Tags: null, crystal-reports

Currently in crystal reports working on a formula that will sum up monthly payments, if and only if the cancel date is null. As in I want to be able to sum up the payments where there is no cancel date.

The fields are

{ARSLREHABSET.ARSLRHSETPMTAMT} and {ARSLREHABSET.ARSLRHSETCANCDATE}

I have tried using:

```
sum({ARSLREHABSET.ARSLRHSETPMTAMT}, isNull({ARSLREHABSET.ARSLRHSETCANCDATE}))
```

without any success, it says "A field is required here" on the second half of the argument. I have had no prior experience to crystal reports, and cannot find any good examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create a Formula, name it `payment`(or what you want)

```
if isnull({ARSLREHABSET.ARSLRHSETCANCDATE})
then 
{ARSLREHABSET.ARSLRHSETPMTAMT}
else 
0
```

Place this formula(`payment`) on your report.

- Right Click on this Field.
- Go to Insert then Summary.
- [image]
- This will add a field to your report footer, and contains sum of all payments where there is no cancel date.
- Now if you want new column then leave it as it is or suppress it if you don't want it on your report.

Comment: Would you be able to help with another issue?